# MapKit Overlays consuming massive CPU resources

Tags: ios, overlay, mapkit, shapefile, proj

I'm overlaying the contents of a third-party shapefile. Some of the polygons consist of 138,000 points, most of them of about 3,000-8,000. In total there are 125 polygons.

Is that normal? Can I in some way, reduce the granularity of the polygons? CPU consumption peaks at over 190% on iPhone 5, and it takes a few minutes before the first overlays pop up.

Comment: I tried thinning out the points by only taking each 100th, and also by only taking another point if it is at least 50m away from the previously added point, however the results are unusable. The provided shapefile is simply too heavy to use with MapKit.

Comment: You can run in through simplify geometries in Quantum GIS, postgres/postgis, or another program.  Otherwise TileMill should be pretty good - I've been rendering a US map with 6 million polygons in it (all the blocks in the US census).  You might need to get a development version of TileMill if you run out of memory, and be sure to store your shapefile in postgres for speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might consider is using [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) to render the Shapefile down into raster tiles with alpha transparency. You can then use that in either MapKit or the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk). It will be highly performant, plus you can still use interactivity going the Mapbox route. Take this map, which was made from Shapefile data in TileMill: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/newamerica.motw_poverty/page.html#6/40.086/-95.471 The same way that the mouseovers work on the web, you could use Mapbox's `RMInteractiveSource` API to query and show on tap or other gestures.